# @cython.locals(arr=np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1]) not supported?

Tags: cython

It seems that one can't declare np.ndarray in cython.locals in .pxd files. It works with memoryviews but not with np.ndarray. However, there are cases where we need np.ndarray.

In notsupported.py

```
import numpy as np

def func():
    arr = np.ones(2)
    return arr**2
```

In notsupported.pxd

```
import cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.locals(arr=np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1])
cpdef func()
```

Error log:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.locals(arr=np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1])
                                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

notsupported.pxd:6:44: Expected ']', found '='
```

Is there something wrong with this code? What is the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like this isn't supported I assume you're really interested in workarounds. For the purpose of this question I'm assuming you want your code to also be valid in pure Python. I'm also assuming that your code is of the form:

```
def func():
    arr = np.ones(2)
    for n in range(arr.shape[0]):
       arr[n] = # some operation element-by-element
    return arr**2
```

If your code doesn't have the element-by-element section then there's really no benefit to setting the type at all - I don't believe Cython uses the type for Numpy "whole array" operations like the power operator you show here.

My first choice would be to have two variables: `arr` and `arr_view`. `arr` should be untyped, and `arr_view` a memoryview. You only use the memoryview in the element-by-element section. Provided you stick to in-place operations the two share the same memory so modifying one modifies the other:

```
def func():
    arr = np.ones(2)
    arr_view = arr
    for n in range(arr_view.shape[0]):
        arr_view[n] = ...
    return arr**2
```

The pxd file is then:

```
@cython.locals(arr_view=np.int_t[:])
cpdef func()
```

My second choice would be to type `arr` as a memoryview, and use `np.asarray` when you want to do "whole array" operations

```
def func():
    arr = np.ones(2)
    for n in range(arr.shape[0]):
       arr[n] = # some operation element-by-element
    return np.asarray(arr)**2
```

with pxd:

```
@cython.locals(arr=nnp.int_t[:])
cpdef func()
```

`np.asarray` is essentially a no-op if it's passed an array, and can usuaully avoid a copy if passed a memoryview, so it won't slow things down too much.

---

A third option is to use the `arr.base` object of a memoryview to get the underlying Numpy array. This loses pure Python compatibility though since `arr.base` is often `None` when `arr` is a Numpy array. Therefore I don't really recommend it here.